# I had loaded my index.html on webserver previously. Now as I am replacing it with the new index.html, the changes are not showing up now

Tags: web-hosting, html, ftp

I used the filezilla client to delete the index.html from webserver and upload the new one. P.S. When I open the domain, I can view the previously loaded index.html now.

I tried to hard reload. But it is not showing up still. I accessed the index.html file from the ftp.. and it is showing the true result. I hope hard reload is by pressing F12 and rightclick on refresh and clicking 'Empty cache and hard reload'.

Comment: If you upload the index file via FTP and it shows the true result from accessing via FTP, did you reload the FTP url after copying the file in and before trying to download the index file to make sure its there in the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of shared web hosting companies occupy server level caching on their servers, It'll take around 15 minutes to update.

Try to call your page like this

index.html?sth